# Meteor: Error when updating database externally: Unknown id for changed

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an Android app that sends data to my Meteor app and databases are updated. If I check mongo from command line with `meteor mongo` the new records are saved, but in the browser console I see this error:

```
Exception in queued task: Error: Unknown id for changed: wtoa4JGTjYsAiddEs
at Object.LocalCollection._CachingChangeObserver.self.applyChange.changed (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:3809:13)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:421:13
at _.extend.runTask (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?81e2f06cff198adaa81b3bc09fc4f3728b7370ec:692:11)
at _.extend.flush (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?81e2f06cff198adaa81b3bc09fc4f3728b7370ec:720:10)
at _.extend.drain (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?81e2f06cff198adaa81b3bc09fc4f3728b7370ec:728:12)
at LocalCollection.update (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:779:22)
at Object.Mongo.Collection.self._connection.registerStore.update (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo.js?052f30e968644b2b39a96605ffee73a7684ff37b:273:30)
at Object._.extend.registerStore._.each.store.(anonymous function) [as update] (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?41b62dcceb3ce0de6ca79c6aed088cccde6a44d8:3913:48)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?41b62dcceb3ce0de6ca79c6aed088cccde6a44d8:4663:19
at Array.forEach (native)
```

And I can't see the changes in the template. If I refresh the page then all new data appears.

I don't know what I'm missing...

PS: First question asked and no english-speaker. Sorry if something isn't well explained.

**EDIT:** Publish is like in the docs.

```
Meteor.publish("bots", function () {
    return Bots.find();
  });
```

For insertion in database I use `Meteor.call()` in server code, using Iron Route for the HTTP GET.

```
Router.route('/get', {where: 'server'})
  .get(function () {
    ...  ...

    Meteor.call("addBot", params);

    ... ...
  });
```

`params` are in the query.

**EDIT2:**

In my template I just subscribe to the collection and use a helper to get all the fields.

```
Meteor.subscribe("bots"); 
... ...
Template.controlpanel.helpers({
  bots: function () {
    return Bots.find();   
  } 
});
```

And the html code is:

```
<tbody>
  {{#each bots}}
  <tr>
    {{> bot}}
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

No other routes involved and no events.

Comment: Please show your publication and subscription code snippets.

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy Nothing specially different from docs.

Comment: Why are you using a server side route for your insert method? You can use a simple event handler on your template. I think you may have two problems. 1) Your template 2) Your routes (which indicate why a page refresh works). You really need to share more code. Relevant pieces at least. Like the template, the subscription (you just showed the publish there), relevant routes, helpers, event handlers etc.

Comment: How do you pass the params to your /get route? A server side get/post request is not the way to insert data in a meteor app. You use event handlers for that, possibly a submit event on a form and within the event handler, you call addBot method.

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy I get the data from an Android app, external to Meteor. The problem is not there because the insertion is done.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for getting this error is most probably that you push records into the database but minimongo doesn't know about them until you refresh the browser.

How do you exactly add the external data to monogdb?

Comment: I get the data via HTTP get and the `Meteor.call()` to update the database. Thanks